# Vee Validate 3 catch errors on form submit

Tags: vue.js, error-handling, submit, vee-validate

How do i catch if form submit fails in vee-validate? I have the following component

```
<template>
  <ValidationObserver tag='div' class='bg-white pt-6 pb-6 mb-4' v-slot='{ handleSubmit }'>

   <form
      @submit.prevent='handleSubmit(onSubmit)'
      class='mx-auto rounded-lg overflow-hidden pt-6 pb-6 space-y-10'
      :class="{'is-loading' : isLoading}"
    >
      <div class='flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6'>
        <div class='w-full md:w-3/12 px-3 mb-6 md:mb-5'>
          <ValidationProvider v-slot='{ classes, errors }' rules='required' name='Anrede'>
          <CustomSelect :options='gender'
                        placeholder='Anrede *'
                        v-model='form.gender'
                        :class="classes"
          />
            <span class='text-mb-error font-medium text-sm italic'>{{ errors[0] }}</span>
          </ValidationProvider>
        </div>
</div>
   <div class='block'>
        <button
          class='bg-secondary hover:bg-secondary-200 text-white py-3 px-4 w-full mt-5 focus:outline-none'
          type='submit'
        >
          Registrieren
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </ValidationObserver>
</template>
```

as method I have the following function

```
 onSubmit () {
      alert()
      console.log(this.$refs.observer)

      this.$emit('onSendRegistration', this.form)
    }
```

which works fine if form is valid but if it fails never gets executed. Where can I catch if form validation fails?

Comment: Let me know if my answer was of any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation:

> [`handleSubmit`] calls validation like validate and mutates provider's state, accepts a callback to be run only if the validation is successful.

So to run a callback in the case of an error in validation you would have to trigger the validation programmatically using a `ref` in the `ValidationObserver`.

Your opening `ValidationObserver` tag would now look like this:

```html
...
<ValidationObserver tag='div' class='bg-white pt-6 pb-6 mb-4' ref='form'>
...
```

Your opening `form` tag should be now like this:

```html
...
<form
  @submit.prevent='onSubmit'
  class='mx-auto rounded-lg overflow-hidden pt-6 pb-6 space-y-10'
  :class="{'is-loading' : isLoading}"
>
...
```

And your `onSubmit` method should be something like this:

```js
onSubmit () {
  this.$refs.form.validate().then(success => {
    if (!success) {
      // run your error code here
    }

    alert('Form has been submitted!');

  });
}
```

Besides this programmatic approach there's no equivalent to `handleSubmit` for running a callback function after an invalid form submission.

Check the docs for more info about the [programmatic access with `$refs`](https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/forms.html#programmatic-access-with-refs).